# Open a port of a docker zookeeper container

Tags: linux, networking, apache-zookeeper

I'm installing zookeeper on my container.

What I've done is:

```
root@46966b33c3a1:/opt:> wget https://downloads.apache.org/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.6.2/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin.tar.gz
root@46966b33c3a1:/opt:> tar zxf apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin.tar.gz
root@46966b33c3a1:/opt:> cd apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin
root@46966b33c3a1:/opt/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin:> cp conf/zoo_sample.cfg conf/zoo.cfg
root@46966b33c3a1:/opt/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin:> vi conf/zoo.cfg
root@46966b33c3a1:/opt/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin:> ./bin/zkServer.sh start
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/opt/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin/data
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
```

It looked like zk sever started without a problem.

However, when I try to connect to zk CLI, an error occurs:

```
2021-02-09 22:59:16,920 [myid:localhost:2181] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1167] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181.
2021-02-09 22:59:16,921 [myid:localhost:2181] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1169] - SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
JLine support is enabled
2021-02-09 22:59:17,001 [myid:localhost:2181] - WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1285] - Session 0x0 for sever localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:344)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1275)
```

So, I checked a connection to 2181 port.

```
root@46966b33c3a1:/opt/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin:> telnet localhost 2181
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Network is unreachable

root@46966b33c3a1:/opt/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin:> hostname -i
172.17.0.2
root@46966b33c3a1:/opt/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin:> telnet 172.17.0.2 2181
Trying 172.17.0.2...
telnet: connect to address 172.17.0.2: Connection refused
```

Connection is refused.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [zookeeper official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/zookeeper). You can use docker-compose instead of doing manual zookeeper installation inside a docker.
Here is a sample docker-compose file. You can modify other configs from documentation based on your requirement.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181
      ZOO_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOO_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOO_SYNC_LIMIT: 2

  zoo2:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo2
    ports:
      - 2182:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 2
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181
      ZOO_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOO_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOO_SYNC_LIMIT: 2

  zoo3:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo3
    ports:
      - 2183:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 3
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181
      ZOO_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOO_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOO_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for some reason, I have to use a certain docker image because of a security issue in my company. That base image is a simple CentOS 7 with security, java, and some other settings.